# Step into debugging not working in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using PhpStorm and new to PHP.

I am using Xdebug, MAMP Bitnami server.

It seems the step into a PHP object constructor is not working.

Below is my code:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["username"]; ?><br>
Your server url is: <?php echo $_POST["server"]; ?>

<?php 
echo "Before connecting";
try {
require_once ('cmis_repository_wrapper.php');
$serverurl = $_POST["server"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$client = new CMISService($serverurl, $username, $password);
echo "Connected\n";
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Message: " .$e->getMessage();
}
?>

</body>
```

I am not able to step into the `CMISService` object's constructor. I am able to step into `require_once` method but.

Below is the code for CMISService's construct method:

```
function __construct($url, $username, $password, $options = null, array $addlCurlOptions = array ()) {
    parent :: __construct($url, $username, $password, $options, $addlCurlOptions);
    $this->_link_cache = array ();
    $this->_title_cache = array ();
    $this->_objTypeId_cache = array ();
    $this->_type_cache = array ();
    $this->_changeToken_cache = array ();
}
```

Comment: My normal debugging is working and BPs are hit...i was using the zero configuration debugging https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

Answer (score 0):

It seems i had not included my cmis_service class in my code, that's why obivously it was not working.

Blame it on my naive php knowledge :(

Below is the updated code and its working

```
    <html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["username"]; ?><br>
Your server url is: <?php echo $_POST["server"]; ?>

<?php 
echo "Before connecting";
try {
require_once ('cmis_repository_wrapper.php');
require_once ('cmis_service.php');
$serverurl = $_POST["server"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$client = new CMISService($serverurl, $username, $password);
echo "Connected\n";
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Message: " .$e->getMessage();
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```